# react native map polyline is not showing

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

This is my code.

```
<View style={styles.map}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
        />
        {
          this.state.allow_set_location ?
            <View style={styles.markerFixed}>
              <Image style={styles.marker} source={marker} />
            </View> : null
        }

        <Polyline
          coordinates={this.state.route_data}
          strokeWidth={1}
          strokeColor="red"
          fillColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
        />
      </View>
```

i am not able to get the polyline.
my route_data is array of objects, like `[{latitude: data, longitude: data}.....]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Polyline` should be wrapped by `MapView` component, instead of side by side.

```js
       <View style={styles.map}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={this.state.region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
        >
          <Polyline
            coordinates={this.state.route_data}
            strokeWidth={1}
            strokeColor="red"
            fillColor="rgba(255,0,0,0.5)"
          />
       </MapView>
      </View>
```